# How to "partially bind" fast changing progress in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

For example, suppose a list of downloading files. Each item is showing the percentage of download.

As the documentation says, on `onBindViewHolder()`, when payload is empty, I bind fully as usual, and when there is a payload, I bind only the percentage.

I added only a few items to a RecyclerView, so all items were fully visible. I called `notifyItemchanged()` with a payload about 16 times but `onBindViewHolder()` was called back only once or twice, and those payloads were not even the latest one.

One thought that came to me was that `notifyItemChanged()` could be dropped when the Adapter or RecyclerView is busy updating. In my case the progress change is quite fast. So when I called `notifyItemChanged()`, the RecyclerView might have been processing `onBindViewHolder()` for a previous `notifyItemChanged()`. If it is so, how can I make sure at least the last `notifyItemChanged()` processed? What is the best practice for this kind of thing, which I think is not uncommon.

Comment: Could you post your onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder,int,List<Object>) implementation? I've run into the same problem.